# (Non)LinearModelFit hangs on "trivial" linear fit (Fit succeeds)

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, fitting

A simplified version of my function and a simplified subset of my data (real data also has weights, if that matters, but I tested both with and without those):

```
myfunc[x_, a_] = 8*a*Exp[-8/Sqrt[x]]/(Sqrt[x]*Abs[WhittakerW[E*I/Sqrt[x], 
                                                             1/2, 8/10*I*Sqrt[x]*a]]^2)
mydata = {{4.5, 195}, {2.9, 175}, {2.1, 95}}
```

`myfunc` also needs a global rescaling. If I want to fit both parameter `a` and the scale, `NonlinearModelFit` works great out of the box and quickly (a `Timing` on a fresh kernel returned 0.6 seconds):

```
NonlinearModelFit[mydata, scale*myfunc[x, a], {scale, a}, {x}]
```

If, however, I only want to find the best scaling for an `a` value of my choice, this:

```
NonlinearModelFit[mydata, scale*myfunc[x, 4], {scale}, {x}]
```

takes forever in my computer (hangs until I abort). I am surprised: why the "complicated" fit works so easily, and this "trivial" linear one not?

`LinearModelFit` is supposedly the right tool here, but:

```
LinearModelFit[mydata, {myfunc[x, 4]}, {x}, IncludeConstantBasis -> False]
```

hangs in the same way (I let it run for about 1.5 hours, then aborted). There must be something wrong I am doing.
I tried using 4.0 instead of 4 for `a`, enclosing with an `N[]`, adding `WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision`, suggesting a good starting value for `scale`, but I get the same result.

`NonlinearModelFit` works adding `Method -> "NMinimize"`, although it is slow (`Timing` gave 19 seconds), and raises a warning

> NonlinearModelFit::lmnl: The model `(32 E^(-(8/Sqrt[x])) scale)/(Sqrt[x] Abs[WhittakerW[(I E)/Sqrt[x],1/2,(16 I Sqrt[x])/5]]^2)` is linear in the parameters `{scale}`, but a nonlinear method or non-Euclidean norm was specified, so nonlinear methods will be used.

I do not really know what `NMinimize` is doing here, I guess it applies the "right" simplification to `myfunc`, so the computation is easier?

Finally, after wasting one day, `Fit` just works:

```
Fit[mydata, {myfunc[x, 4]}, {x}]
```

This reinforces my impression that I just need to apply some magical simplification, that `Fit` always employs, that `NonlinearModelFit` uses only for the two-parameter fit, and that `Method -> "NMinimize"` will cause. Is `LinearModelFit` evaluating `myfunc` much more times than needed? I am clueless.

`LinearModelFit` has several niceties that I would rather not give up for what appears to be such a stupid issue. Furthermore, I am probably going to learn a new important Mathematica quirk from this. Thus:

Why the above code, using (Non)LinearModelFit for a simple `scale*f[x]` model, hangs, and how should I modify it to make it work?

---

For completeness, I am adding some tests on my system (12.2.0.0) after @xzczd suggestions in the comments. This one:

```
Clear[undefinedname]
FindFit[{undefinedname}, b WhittakerW[I, 1, I], b, {x}]
```

hangs, regardless of whether some data is passed. `LinearModelFit[{undefinedname},...]` instead won't get tricked and stop immediately. However, passing real data, those do *not* hang:

```
FindFit[mydata, b WhittakerW[I, 1, I * 1.0], ... ]
LinearModelFit[mydata, Abs[WhittakerW[I, 1, I * 1.0]], ... ]
LinearModelFit[mydata, Abs[WhittakerW[I, 1, I]], ...] (*5x slower than the previous one*)

NonlinearModelFit[mydata, scale*myfunc[x, 4], {scale}, {x},
                  Method -> "ConjugateGradient"] (*Hangs with InteriorPoint*)
```

It sounds like both the linear fitter and `InteriorPoint` get confused when they cannot explicitly evaluate `WhittakerW` (as it always is when the function depends on `x`).

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. `LinearModelFit` doesn't hang in _v9_. A simpler example that hangs: `Clear[aha, myfunc]; myfunc[x_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := WhittakerW[I, 1, I a];  FindFit[{aha}, scale myfunc[x, 1], scale, {x}]`. BTW, this sampe doesn't hang in _v9.0.1_, but if I change `myfunc[x, 1]` to `myfunc[x, 3.47303]`, `FindFit` hangs. (Yeah `myfunc[x, 3.47302` doesn't hang in _v9_. ) Have you reported this to WRI?

Comment: This seems to be related to the method `InteriorPoint`. All other available methods give an output within a minute: `{"Gradient", "ConjugateGradient"(*, "InteriorPoint"*), "QuasiNewton", "Newton", "NMinimize",  "LevenbergMarquardt"}`.

Comment: @xzczd Very interesting. It took me a while before realizing you really meant to pass an undefined `{aha}`, but it does hang! I updated the question with a couple of tests.
Good catch about simply changing method, although I have to give up linear fitting that way.
No I haven't reported it yet, I was assuming there was some simple obscure option to pass to solve the problem. I will now.

Answer (score 3):

I hope that your real data consists of more than 3 data points when fitting a function with 3 parameters (`a`, `b`, and an error variance).

While I don't know why the functions hang, for your function there is a simple fix.  Because `myfunc[x, 4]` does not change with the scaling parameter, just replace the predictor with the values of the function.  Then both `NonlinearModelFit` and 'LinearModelFit` work fine.

```
myfunc[x_, a_] = 8*a*Exp[-8/Sqrt[x]]/(Sqrt[x]*
     Abs[WhittakerW[E*I/Sqrt[x], 1/2, 8/10*I*Sqrt[x]*a]]^2)

(* Replace the predictor with the result of the function *)
mydata = {{4.5, 195}, {2.9, 175}, {2.1, 95}};
mydata[[All, 1]] = myfunc[#, 4] & /@ mydata[[All, 1]];

(* Fit the model to the data *)
NonlinearModelFit[mydata, b x, {{b, 16}}, x] // Normal
(* 18.4684 x *)
LinearModelFit[mydata, x, x, IncludeConstantBasis -> False] // Normal
(* 18.4684 x *)
```

I know that doesn't answer the "why" part of your question.

Comment: Yes, those 3 points are just for allowing people here to play around themselves if they wish, real data has more points.

Comment: Good idea, before asking I was changing y = b f(x) to z = (y/f(x)) = b, but doing instead y = b X = b (f(x)) seems better, when adding errors to y they stay unaltered, and one can easily switch to more general linear fits.

Comment: Hmm… I didn't expect the post is so unpopular. (My bounty doesn't even attract an upvote!  ) Anyway, here's already an answer that meet the goal, so +6 :) .